# React Carousel target div elements

Tags: reactjs, carousel, element

I am learning to make custom `Carousel` by using React and Typescript. For styling I used [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) and `scss`. I found from one Article how to make Carousel. My carousel works fine.
I have made four `div` elements. when the carousel image slide will change, I want to change background-color of the `div` elements inot `orange color`. But Don't know how to do that.

I share my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-slide-zt7kp?file=/src/App.tsx)

**This is my Carousel component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, memo, useCallback } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface ICarousel {
  children: JSX.Element[];
  currentSlide?: number;
  autoPlay?: boolean;
  dots?: boolean;
  interval?: number;
  arrow?: boolean;
}

const IMG_WIDTH = 320;
const IMG_HEIGHT = 700;

export default memo(
  ({
    children,
    autoPlay = false,
    dots = false,
    interval = 3000,
    arrow = false
  }: ICarousel) => {
    const [currentSlide, setSlide] = useState(0);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(autoPlay);
    const timer = useRef<any>(undefined);

    const slides = children.map((slide, index) => (
      <CarouselSlide key={index}>{slide}</CarouselSlide>
    ));

    const handleSlideChange = useCallback(
      (index: number) =>
        setSlide(
          index > slides.length - 1 ? 0 : index < 0 ? slides.length - 1 : index
        ),
      [slides]
    );

    const createInterval = useCallback(() => {
      timer.current = setInterval(() => {
        handleSlideChange(currentSlide + 1);
      }, interval);
    }, [interval, handleSlideChange, currentSlide]);

    const destroyInterval = useCallback(() => {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (autoPlay) {
        createInterval();
        return () => destroyInterval();
      }
    }, [autoPlay, createInterval, destroyInterval]);

    return (
      <CarouselContainer
        onMouseEnter={() => {
          if (autoPlay) {
            destroyInterval();
          }
        }}
        onMouseLeave={() => {
          if (autoPlay) {
            createInterval();
          }
        }}
      >
        <CarouselSlides currentSlide={currentSlide}>{slides}</CarouselSlides>
        {arrow ? (
          <div>
            <LeftButton onClick={() => handleSlideChange(currentSlide - 1)}>
              &#10094;
            </LeftButton>
            <RightButton onClick={() => handleSlideChange(currentSlide + 1)}>
              &#10095;
            </RightButton>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {dots ? (
          <Dots>
            {slides.map((i, index) => (
              <Dot
                key={index}
                onClick={() => handleSlideChange(index)}
                active={currentSlide === index}
              />
            ))}
          </Dots>
        ) : null}
      </CarouselContainer>
    );
  }
);

const Buttons = styled.a`
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  position: absolute;
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
`;

const RightButton = styled(Buttons)`
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  right: 0;
`;

const LeftButton = styled(Buttons)`
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  left: 0;
`;

const Dots = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;

const Dot = styled.span<{ active: boolean }>`
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  background-color: ${({ active }) => (active ? `red` : `#eeeeee`)};
`;

const CarouselContainer = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: ${IMG_WIDTH}px;
  height: ${IMG_HEIGHT}px;
  img {
    /* change the margin and width to fit the phone mask */
    width: ${IMG_WIDTH - 20}px;
    height: ${IMG_HEIGHT - 50}px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  z-index: 1;
`;

const CarouselSlide = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
`;

const CarouselSlides = styled.div<{
  currentSlide: ICarousel["currentSlide"];
}>`
  display: flex;
  ${({ currentSlide }) =>
    ` transform: translateX(-${currentSlide ? currentSlide * 100 + `%` : 0})`};
  transition: transform 300ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

**This where I am using the Carousel component**

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import "./styles.scss";
    import Carousel from "./carousel";
    
    export const imgUrls = [
      `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455849318743-b2233052fcff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`,
      `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`,
      `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`,
      `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`
    ];
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <main className="Testeru">
            <div className="phone-left">
// I want change background color of this div element
              <div className="phone-left-upper">left upper</div> 
              <div className="phone-left-lower">left-lower</div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="phone-slider">
              <div className="mobile_overlay">
                <Carousel autoPlay>
                  {imgUrls.map((i) => {
                    return (
                      <img
                        key={i}
                        src={i}
                        alt=""
                        style={{
                          borderRadius: `20px`
                        }}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                </Carousel>
              </div>
            </div>
    // I want change background color of this div element
            <div className="phone-right">
              <div className="phone-right-upper">right upper</div>
              <div className="phone-right-lower">right-lower</div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
```